# Unable to login to iOS beta using Facebook

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, facebook, authentication

When trying to login to the iOS beta app (1.0.1.80) I get the following error message:

> [image]

This happens before being offered the opportunity to enter my Facebook credentials (although I'm logged into Facebook on my phone anyway, so I'm not sure I'd *get* the opportunity). Upon pressing OK, I get directed back to the iOS app with an error message simply saying "Unknown Facebook Error":

> [image]

When logging into to app available via the App Store, this error *doesn't* exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed. There was a problem with our Facebook app configuration on the server.